# Powershell Start-Process with Credentials runs forever

Tags: powershell, credentials, freeze, windows-server-2016, start-process

I have an issue with the start-process command in Powershell, when using the -credentials parameter the Powershell_ISE is running forever, it never finishes.

The issue seems to be on one server though, so when i run it on this specific server (Windows Server 2016) the Powershell_ISE runs forever and i cannot stop it, then it just gets stuck in stopping mode.

When i run the exact same lines in Powershell_ISE on another server, it runs without any issues.

On the server im having the issue on, i have tried to use a newly created account to be sure its not a profile related issue.

I have set the executionpolicy to unrestricted.
And yes i run the Powershell_ISE as an administrator.

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

    $username = "DOMAIN\USERNAME"
    $password = "PASSWORD"
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString “$password” -AsPlainText -Force

    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $Password)

    Start-Process Notepad.exe -Credential $Credentials
```

The usage of Notepad.exe is just something im using for testing, i use this function in another matter, but it doesnt work with any process.

I have to use this server for this function, and its because this server is hosting a RDS Tool in IIS in production.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?